# Mistake with a normalisation factor?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Consider this [image]

I do not think this is right. In particular, I do not agree that $A=QDQ$.  If this were to be true, since $Q$ is made out of the eigenvectors, we would need $Q$ to be orthonormal. But this is not true since the eigenvectors, as given have length $\sqrt{\frac{M}{M+1}}$.

Can someone clarify what is going on here?

Perhaps there is a typo in the normalization constant?

Comment: The $Q$ in the source is correct, but $D_{k,k}$ is not: the numerator inside the cosine should be $k\pi$, not $2k\pi$.

Comment: I agree that the eigenvalues do not have the 2. When you say that $Q$ is correct, do you also agree with the text which is implying that $Q$ is orthonormal?

Comment: The columns of $Q$ are orthonormal.